# urlNode.objectForKeyedSubscript("href") as? String - Swift 2.3 / Swift 3 error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scripting, alamofire

My code crawls up an HTML page, searches for tags, reads a table on the website and populates a tableView. This worked like a charm in Swift 2.2 but since I've updated Cocoapods, I'm having this error that is refusing to go.

Here is my function:

```
if let secondColumn = rowElement.childAtIndex(1) as? HTMLElement {
        title = secondColumn.textContent
            .stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
            .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withString: "")
        if let urlNode = secondColumn.firstNodeMatchingSelector("a") {
        if let urlString = urlNode.objectForKeyedSubscript("href") as? String {
            url = NSURL(string: urlString)
            if url == nil {
                url = NSURL.init(string: "www.mywebsitelink.com")
            }
            }
        }
    }
```

The error is in: `urlNode.objectForKeyedSubscript("href") as? String`

Error:

> Downcast from 'String?' to 'String' only unwraps optionals; did you
>   mean to use '!'?

This worked fine before and I haven't changed any code at all in this file.

Dependencies:

- [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)
- [HTMLReader](https://github.com/cmoulton/grokHTMLAndDownloads)

Steps taken so far:

- Updated code to Swift 2.3 and Swift 3 - doesn't work.
- Cleaned code, deleted derived data, etc. - doesn't work.
- Tried to flip versions of the dependencies to older versions - doesn't work.
- Tried to change optional values i.e. added / removed '!' or '?', tried to change the function by removing 'if let' and just declaring it.

Images of Changes:

Error: conditional binding must have optional type, not string.
[image]

Error: unavailable for scripting
[image]

Please help.

Comment: @sasquatch - not sure where your post disappeared. We were getting on to something ...

Comment: I deleted it because it was not the right answer

Comment: Oh okay .. still stuck at this :(  .. I tried all you've said before (and even now), not sure where the problem is.

Comment: I'm away from my system, if I get a working code, I will post that as answer.

Comment: Thanks. Will watch out for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it using this syntax:

if let urlString = urlNode["href"] {
}

Not sure if it is correct but getting rid of the text after the '.' seems to be working so far.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your original construct,

```
urlNode.objectForKeyedSubscript("href")
```

is of type `String?` (optional string) not some other type. Thus the `as?` cast is wrong. You should just use

```
if let urlString = urlNode.objectForKeyedSubscript("href")? {}
```